# Ellipse bounding rectangle and quadrangle bounding ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry

I am stuck solving this geometry problem.

> Given ellipse $x^2 + 4 y^2 = 32$ is bounding a rectangle whose height
>   is the double of its width. At the apexes of rectangle are tangent
>   lines to the ellipse. What is the ratio of rectangle area and
>   obtained quadrangle?

What I could do is the following:

I transformed the equation to this form:

$$\frac{x^{2}}{32}+\frac{y^{2}}{8} = 1$$

and I got $a^{2}=32$ and $b^{2}=8$. The ratio of the rectangle if x and y are sides of rectangle is: $x:y = 2:1$ so $P=2y^2$. The equation of tangent line at $M(z,c)$ is

$$\frac{z\cdot x}{a^2} + \frac{c\cdot y}{b^2} = 1$$

I really have no clue what to do here to get this ratio. Any hints would be helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height is twice the width means if $x$ is the width and $y$ is the height then $x:y=1:2.$ But I think it will be easier if you say the width and height are $2z$ and $2c$ so that the rectangle has a vertex at $(z,c).$ Then the height-to-width ratio says $c=2z$.

Can you continue from there?

Comment: Thank you! I solved it.